# Fastest way to highlight row / column corresponding to selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a large excel sheet(482 rows x 654 cols) with loads of formulas calculated, and I need to find the most efficient way to highlight the row/column corresponding to the selected row.

I tried 2 methods:

1. Conditional formatting with the formula:

```
=OR(CELL(“col”)=COLUMN(),CELL(“row”)=ROW())
```

and on

```
Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
target.Calculate
```

2. A macro that removes previous formatting and adds new formatting referencing the selected cell.

Both solutions trigger on selection change, and they slow down the use of the sheet by allot.
I have even tried to set a delay of 1 or 2 seconds, to only run the last action that the user made, canceling the event for action 1, if action 2 happens in that time-frame.

Does anyone have any advanced wisdom for me in this case, like a different trigger, or a hidden setting in Excel that would highlight current row/column more clearly than how excel does it by default?

Comment: `Worksheet_SelectionChange` use `target.column` and `target.row`, reset the selection if different, even check the column differs and format, and check row differs and format

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Public lngRow As Long
Public lngCol As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


    Cells.Interior.Color = XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexNone

    If lngCol = 0 Or lngRow = 0 Then
        lngCol = Target.Column
        lngRow = Target.Row
        FormatRow
        FormatCol
    Else
        If lngCol <> Target.Column Then
            lngCol = Target.Column
            FormatCol
        End If
        If lngRow <> Target.Row Then
            lngRow = Target.Row
            FormatRow
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function FormatRow()
    Dim r As Excel.Range
    Set r = Rows(lngRow)
    r.Interior.Color = RGB(230, 230, 230)
End Function
Function FormatCol()
    Dim r As Excel.Range
    Set r = Columns(lngCol)
    r.Interior.Color = RGB(230, 230, 230)
End Function
```

Comment: `Dim r As Excel.Range` should be moved at the module declarations level or inside each `FormmatXXX()` function (which should actually be `Sub`s)

Comment: @DisplayName thanks, the range was initially in doing this set from the initial function.  I have, of late, coded subs as functions with no return, this I believe has no bad effect, and allows me to do things easier, like return from a function in debugging/testing.